# Javascript function only executes every other time

Tags: javascript, removechild

I'm working on a letter guessing game and I have a scoreboard at the bottom that shows how many lives the player has left before they lose the game. I have an onscreen keyboard that the user clicks to choose which letter they want to guess.

Everything works fine, except for removing the player's 'lives'.  I have the lives as images that are in an ordered list. On each button click, a function checks to see if that button press matches a letter in the phrase. If it doesn't, it needs to remove a life from the ordered list, and add 1 to the missed count.

Adding 1 to the missed counts works on every wrong button press, but removing the heart only works on every other one, and I'm not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function checkLetter(clickedButton) {
  const letters = document.getElementsByClassName('letter');
  let letterFound = null;
  for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i += 1) {
    if (clickedButton === letters[i].textContent) {
      letters[i].classList.add('show');
      letterFound = true;
    }
  }
  return letterFound;
}

function changeScore() {
  let scoreboardList = document.querySelector('ol');
  scoreboardList.removeChild(scoreboardList.childNodes[0]);
}

qwerty.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const button = e.target;
  const buttonText = button.textContent;
  checkLetter(buttonText);
  if (checkLetter(buttonText) == null) {
    missed += 1;
    changeScore();
    console.log(missed);
  } else {
    button.classList.add('chosen');
  }
});
```

```html
   

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Wheel of Success!</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-container">
      <div id="overlay" class="start">
        <h2 class="title">Wheel of Success</h2>
        <a class="btn__reset">Start Game</a>
      </div>

      <div id="banner" class="section">
        <h2 class="header">Wheel of Success</h2>
      </div>

      <div id="phrase" class="section">
        <ul></ul>
      </div>
      <div id="qwerty" class="section">
        <div class="keyrow">
          <button>q</button><button>w</button><button>e</button><button>r</button><button>t</button><button>y</button><button>u</button><button>i</button><button>o</button><button>p</button>
        </div>
        <div class="keyrow">
          <button>a</button><button>s</button><button>d</button><button>f</button><button>g</button><button>h</button><button>j</button><button>k</button><button>l</button>
        </div>
        <div class="keyrow">
          <button>z</button><button>x</button><button>c</button><button>v</button><button>b</button><button>n</button><button>m</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="scoreboard" class="section">
        <ol>
          <li class="tries"><img src="images/liveHeart.png" height="35px" width="30px"></li>
          <li class="tries"><img src="images/liveHeart.png" height="35px" width="30px"></li>
          <li class="tries"><img src="images/liveHeart.png" height="35px" width="30px"></li>
          <li class="tries"><img src="images/liveHeart.png" height="35px" width="30px"></li>
          <li class="tries"><img src="images/liveHeart.png" height="35px" width="30px"></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant html and css to fix the console error. What is qwerty for example

Comment: You don’t need to run the checkLetter function twice in the event listener. Having it in the if statement like that will run it. Either that or assign it to a variable the first time and evaluate that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, your call to `scoreboardList.removeChild(scoreboardList.childNodes[0]);` will remove the first node. In your case, this is not necessarily an element, but can also be a text node containing only white space. This is probably the reason, why only every second call looks like it is doing something. The other one is removing white space. I have changed the code to explicitly remove the first "heart" node instead. And, of course, what Lewis mentioned in his comment: Don't call `checkLetter` twice. Just use it in the `if` directly.

```js
let missed = 0;

function changeScore() {
  let scoreboardList = document.querySelector('ol');

  // !!!!!! These two lines are the important changes:
  let heart = scoreboardList.querySelector('li:first-child'); // find first heart item
  scoreboardList.removeChild(heart); // remove the heart
}

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  //const button = e.target;
  //const buttonText = button.textContent;
  //if (checkLetter(buttonText) == null) {
    missed += 1;
    changeScore();
    console.log(missed);
  //} else {
  //  button.classList.add('chosen');
  //}
});
```

```html
<div id="scoreboard" class="section">
  <ol>
    <li class="tries"><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/heart/heart_PNG51341.png" height="35px" width="30px"></li>
    <li class="tries"><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/heart/heart_PNG51341.png" height="35px" width="30px"></li>
    <li class="tries"><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/heart/heart_PNG51341.png" height="35px" width="30px"></li>
    <li class="tries"><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/heart/heart_PNG51341.png" height="35px" width="30px"></li>
    <li class="tries"><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/heart/heart_PNG51341.png" height="35px" width="30px"></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update your `changeScore()` method like this:

```
function changeScore() {
  let scoreboardList = document.querySelector('ol');

  // Replace this
  // scoreboardList.removeChild(scoreboardList.childNodes[0]);

  // By this 'EDIT'
  scoreboardList.removeChild(scoreboardList.querySelector('li:first-child'));
}
```

That will remove a heart each time the answer is false.

Comment: Your code should be `var heart = scoreboardList.querySelector('li:first-child'); scoreboardList.removeChild(heart);`. It won't work as written now, since `heart` is never defined.

Comment: That worked! Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.